# Where should "Unassigned" items go when considering a list filter?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, ux-field, ux-designer

I have a large data table and have some filter options. One of these options is the ability to filter by group, i.e. you can view group1, group2, group3, etc. The issue is, every item either has a group, or is unassigned. I want to add a way to filter the list so the user can see just the "unassigned" items, but adding the filter "unassigned" along with the other group names make it difficult because there's not distinction between them. It could just as easily be a group called "unassigned". How should I change this filter dropdown menu so users can easily distinguish that "unassigned devices" are the devices that they havn't used yet? I'd like to avoid creating another filter dropdown if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just separate them by a line or something. [image]

You can also consider adding a checkbox or radio button based on the functionality or the data of the table.

Comment: I was thinking of something similar, I think the line will work well for my design. I do like the checkbox functionality, i will have to go over the code to see how feasible that will be